# Chrome extension - Why some urls that don't match the filters still pass?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, browser, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension that automatically close tabs when visiting specific urls in order to avoid being distracted.

Here are the sites to be closed:
youtube
facebook
reddit
twitter

Weirdly, some urls that don't match the filters are still closed like:
https://hackernoon.com/binance-vs-coinbase-pro-vs-cryptocom-which-one-is-the-one-for-you-ijcn3259

Why?

Code here:

```
  chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function(data) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(data.tabId);

  }, {url: [
    { hostContains: '.youtube' },
    { hostContains: '.twitter' },
    { hostContains: '.reddit' },
    { hostContains: '.facebook' }
    ]
  });
```

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webNavigation API also reports iframes so you should check if `frameId` is `0`:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(data => {
  if (!data.frameId) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(data.tabId);
  }
}, {
  url: [
    { hostContains: '.youtube' },
    { hostContains: '.twitter' },
    { hostContains: '.reddit' },
    { hostContains: '.facebook' },
  ],
});
```

BTW it might make sense to use chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted event as it's reported earlier when the tab only starts loading.

Comment: I didn't know that, awesome! Thanks for your working solution and for the onCommitted tips :)
Perfect answer!